# What are the most common methods to model fat tails in the changes of asset prices?

Tags: volatility, statistics, asset-pricing, modeling, asset-returns

I was wondering what the most common, or most popular, ways - in both academia, and industry - there were to model the fat tails of volatility in asset prices changes.

I am presuming a basic Brownian motion random walk, is not what is used, because it will not replicate fat tails. Is that correct? Or am I wrong, and in most cases, a basic Brownian motion is "good enough"? What are more advanced methods that are used, whether it be in terms of stochastic calculus, statistical methods, etc.?

Comment: Are you interested in discrete time or continuous time? Or both?

Comment: I would be interested in either, whatever methods are in common use. I do not know enough about the industry to know what is currently in popular use, or in which circumstances you might prefer one over the other.

Comment: Accepted. Sorry, I assume I was just waiting for more answers and then forgot about the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of discrete time, consider a GARCH model with standardized innovations that follow a Student-$t$ or another (somewhat) heavy-tailed distribution. The dependent variable will have a tail heavier than that due to the GARCH model. (The model generates heavier tails than present in the distribution assumed for the standardized innovations.)

Comment: If you want a reference for "GARCH Student t" it is Bollerslev (1987) in Review of Economics and Statistics, 69(3), p. 542-547. https://www.jstor.org/stable/1925546 as discussed by Richard Hardy here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500445/reference-request-for-t-distribution-garch-maximum-likelihood-estimation